# Add POST form data to http headers on site load in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, http

If a certain cookie is set, I want my WordPress site to load with POST form data. Is it possible using the wp_headers hook? It will be great if someone can explain this with an example.

Answer (score -2):

You can used Ajax JQuery for Wordpress. Here is a sample code:

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        var fname = "Firstname";
        var lname = "Lastname";

        var datas = {
            'action' : 'do_load_postdata',
            'firstname' : rewardid,
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl.loadpostdata, datas, function(response) {
            $('#div-response').html(response);
        });

    });
```

Comment: your code is for sending a post Ajax request via jQuery while the page has been loaded. I looking for a technique to attach post request variables in the header on page load without redirection.